# Extremely tough limit proof for f(x) and g(x)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the following property: for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all $x$, 
$$ \text{if} \space 0 < |x - 2| < \sin^2(\epsilon^2/9) + \epsilon \space \text{then} \space |f(x) - 2| < \epsilon$$
$$ \text{if} \space 0 < |x - 2| < \epsilon^2 \space \text{then} \space |g(x) - 4| < \epsilon$$

Find a $\delta$ such that:
(i) if $0 < |x-2| < \delta \space \text{then} \space |f(x) + g(x) - 6| < \epsilon$

This problem is from Spivak's calculus, so no wonder is it quite hard. Here is my attempt:

Let $|x - 2| < 1 \implies |x| < 3 \implies  x < 3 $

But then I get lost. This is a very difficult problem, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$$\delta = \min\left( \sin^2((\epsilon/2)^2/9) + \epsilon/2, (\epsilon/2)^2\right)$$

then $0 < |x - 2| < \delta \ $ implies

$$0 < | x - 2| < \sin^2((\epsilon/2)^2/9) + \epsilon/2 \ \ \ \hbox{ and }\ \ 0 < | x - 2 | < (\epsilon/2)^2$$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \Rightarrow  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  |f(x) - 2| < \epsilon/2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \   \hbox{ and } \ \ \ \ \ \ |g(x) - 4| < \epsilon/2 \ $

Hence

$$\begin{align} 
| f(x) + g(x) - 6 |   & =  | f(x) - 2 + g(x) - 4| \\
                      & \leq |f(x) - 2| + |g(x) - 4| \\
                      & < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 \\
                      & = \epsilon
\end{align}$$

That is, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \min\left( \sin^2((\epsilon/2)^2/9) + \epsilon/2, (\epsilon/2)^2\right)$. Then

$$0 < |x - 2| < \delta \ \ \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ \ | f(x) + g(x) - 6 | < \epsilon$$

Comment: I like this answer, but did you use trial/error to determine the $\delta$ in the beginning of your answer?

Comment: The 'experimentation' that goes on when you start an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof has already been given to us in these bizarre bounds. I think the purpose of the exercise is to realize that once we have such bounds we can combine them using the kind of "$\epsilon/2$" argument I've written here. If there were three terms $\epsilon/3$, etc.

Comment: How does $|f(x) - 2| < \epsilon/2$ imply from the statement $0 < |x - 2| < \sin^2((\epsilon/2)^2/9) + \epsilon/2$?

Comment: You gave that $$0 < |x - 2| < \sin^2(\epsilon^2/9) + \epsilon  \ \ \Longrightarrow  \ |f(x) - 2| < \epsilon$$
Now replace $\epsilon$ by $\epsilon/2$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was helpufl!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's get some feeling for what the question is asking.

Notice that Spivak's conditions on $f$ and $g$ simply tell you that $f(x)\to 2$ as $x\to 2$, and $g(x)\to 4$ as $x\to 2$. They tell you a bit more than that, of course, by giving you explicit bounds on how close $x$ has to be to $2$ in order to get $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be within a certain distance of their limits. Nevertheless, it's at least obvious that $f(x)+g(x)\to 2+4=6$ as $x\to 2$, and what the problem asks is for you to give similar explcit bounds for that convergence.

We want $f(x) + g(x)$ to be within $\epsilon$ of $6$. Well, what if we simply got $f(x)$ within $\epsilon / 2$ of $2$, and $g(x)$ within $\epsilon / 2$ of $4$? That would do. In that case, the explicit bounds given for $f$ and $g$ tell us that we need:

$$|x - 2| < (\sin\frac {\epsilon^2} {36})^2  +\frac \epsilon 2$$

in order for $f(x)$ to be within $\epsilon/2$ of $2$, and

$$|x - 2| < \frac {\epsilon^2} 4$$

in order for $g(x)$ to be within $\epsilon/2$ of $4$. So $|x - 2|$ needs to be smaller than *both* of those values. Well, hey, that just means it has to be smaller than the minimum:

$$\delta=\min\left((\sin\frac {\epsilon^2} {36})^2  +\frac \epsilon 2, \frac {\epsilon^2} 4\right)$$

Comment: Nice. Small note: the bound for $f$ has the added term $ \cdots + \epsilon$.

Comment: Could it just be minimum of the original given conditions?

Comment: @Amad27 It basically is, but replacing "$\epsilon$" with "$\epsilon/2$".

Comment: But why is the replacement required?

Comment: @Amad27 The original conditions gave something that worked for any $\epsilon$. I am applying these conditions for a specific value, that being $\epsilon/2$ - maybe I should have used different notation, because my $\epsilon$ is not the same as the one in the original conditions. You do this *any* time you want to apply a theorem to a specific case. If you have the theorem $a^2+b^2=c^2$ for a right triangle with sides $a,b,c$, then to apply that to a triangle with sides $x,y,z$, you have to replace $a,b,c$ with $x,y,z$ in the original theorem.